# survey list is not readable after searching

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doreh7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)[image: before filtering]
[image: after filtering]

I am trying to search survey list on the basis of startDate and endDate and on the basis of startDate and endDate, it should return only those surveys which include startDate and endDate. 
so for that I have written a pipe but I think something is wrong with this logic as after searching the survey list is not readable at all. all those conversion of string to javascript date object are overlapping with each other in the template.

```js
import { OrderByPipe } from '../../pipes/order-by.pipe';
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: "app-survey-info",
  templateUrl: "./survey-info.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./survey-info.component.scss"]
})
export class SurveyInfoComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('myCanvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
  surveyRecords: Array<any>;
  startDate;
  endDate;
  date;
  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {

               this.surveyRecords =
               [{ surveyID: 1, surveyName: "survey1", date: '1/10/2016' },
                { surveyID: 9, surveyName: "survey9", date: '1/12/2016' },
                 { surveyID: 3, surveyName: "survey3", date: '9/10/2016' },
                  { surveyID: 5, surveyName: "survey5", date: '11/10/2016' },
                  { surveyID: 6, surveyName: "survey6", date: '16/10/2016' },
                  { surveyID: 7, surveyName: "survey7", date: '19/10/2016' },
                   { surveyID: 8, surveyName: "survey8", date: '21/10/2016' },
                    { surveyID: 4, surveyName: "survey4", date: '10/10/2016' },
                     { surveyID: 10, surveyName: "survey10", date: '1/10/2017' },
                     { surveyID: 2, surveyName: "survey2", date: '5/10/2016' },
                     { surveyID: 11, surveyName: "survey11", date: '5/10/2017' },
                      { surveyID: 12, surveyName: "survey12", date: '15/10/2017' },
                       { surveyID: 13, surveyName: "survey13", date: '25/10/2017' }];
             }
}

//pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})

 

  export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(surveyRecords: any, args ? : any): any {

        if (args.startDate === undefined && args.endDate === undefined) {
            return surveyRecords;
        } else {
// console.log(surveyRecords, args.startDate, args.endDate);
let startDate = new Date(args.startDate);
let endDate = new Date(args.endDate);
if (startDate && endDate) {
//  console.log(surveyRecords);
  if (surveyRecords) {
    for (let i = 0; i < surveyRecords.length; i++) {
      // var surveyRecords[i]=  new Date();
         surveyRecords[i].date = new Date(surveyRecords[i].date);
   //   console.log(surveyRecords[i].date);
      if (
        surveyRecords[i].date >= startDate || surveyRecords[i].date <= endDate
      ) {
const array: any = surveyRecords;
        return array;
    }
  }
}

        }
    }

}
}
```

```html
<mat-nav-list class="surveys">
<mat-form-field class="datepicker">
  <input matInput class="datepicker"
 [(ngModel)]="startDate"
    [matDatepicker]="picker1"
    placeholder="Start Date ">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="datepicker">
  <input matInput class="datepicker"
   [(ngModel)]="endDate"
   [matDatepicker]="picker2"
    placeholder="End Date ">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<!-- <div>{{startDate}}</div> -->
  <strong class="survey-list">Surveys


  </strong>

  <a mat-list-item
   *ngFor="let survey of surveyRecords|orderBy: {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}">
     <span>{{ survey.surveyName }}
<br>
    <strong><small>{{survey.date}}</small></strong></span> </a>

</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz hard to figure out from here

Comment: @RahulSingh, Here it is https://angular-doreh7.stackblitz.io     https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doreh7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now able to implement this sorting filter by further adding 'shortDate' parameter like this:
 `<small>{{survey.date|date:'shortDate'}}</small>`
and changing my pipe code to this:

```
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(surveyRecords: any, args ?: any): any {
    if (args.startDate === undefined || args.endDate === undefined) {
        return surveyRecords;
    } else if (args.startDate === null || args.endDate === null) {
        return surveyRecords;
      } else {
        const startDate = new Date(args.startDate);
        const endDate = new Date(args.endDate);
        const result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < surveyRecords.length; i++) {
          surveyRecords[i].date = new Date(surveyRecords[i].date);
          console.log(surveyRecords[i].date);
          console.log(surveyRecords[i].date.getTime(), startDate.getTime(),
           surveyRecords[i].date.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
          if (surveyRecords[i].date.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() &&
           surveyRecords[i].date.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
            const obj = { surveyID: surveyRecords[i].surveyID,
               surveyName: surveyRecords[i].surveyName,
               date: surveyRecords[i].date };
            result.push(obj);
            console.log(result);
          } else {
         console.log('no record found!!');
          }
        }
        return result;
      }}}
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doreh7?file=index.html)